# Module not Found on Heroku Deploy but Found on Local

Tags: reactjs, heroku

So I tried to deploy my app to Heroku and find this error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/add-credentials/AddEducation' in '/tmp/build_6b46c3e828c5afc20e70a4b1b2232f69/client/src'`

Everything works fine including that module in localhost. What should I change for this to work?

**Complete Build Log**

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.11.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   5.6.x
       engines.yarn (package.json):  1.9.x

       Resolving node version 8.11.x...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.4...
       Bootstrapping npm 5.6.x (replacing 5.6.0)...
       npm 5.6.x installed
       Resolving yarn version 1.9.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.9.4)...
       Installed yarn 1.9.4

-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
       yarn install v1.9.4
       [1/4] Resolving packages...
       [2/4] Fetching packages...
       info fsevents@1.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
       info "fsevents@1.2.4" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
       [3/4] Linking dependencies...
       [4/4] Building fresh packages...
       Done in 13.99s.
       Running heroku-postbuild (yarn)
       yarn run v1.9.4
       $ NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client

       > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_6b46c3e828c5afc20e70a4b1b2232f69/client/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
       > node lib/post_install.js

       added 1546 packages in 41.748s

       > client@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_6b46c3e828c5afc20e70a4b1b2232f69/client
       > react-scripts build

       Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/add-credentials/AddEducation' in '/tmp/build_6b46c3e828c5afc20e70a4b1b2232f69/client/src'


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.te6Qt/_logs/2018-09-14T23_46_37_674Z-debug.log
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "devconnector",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Social network for developers",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.x",
    "npm": "5.6.x",
    "yarn": "1.9.x"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
  "author": "Dian Yuanda",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1",
    "create-react-app": "^1.5.2",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "global": "^4.3.2",
    "gravatar": "^1.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.12",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^9.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check your `package.lock` file, which should include your dependencies' dependencies. It's very likely that something you rely on relies on `add-credentials`.

Comment: I'm using yarn not npm, here's my [yarn.lock](https://pastebin.com/Q575A2j8) what is possibly that something I rely on relies on `add-credentials`? It's a common component like the others and it just called once on [App.js](https://pastebin.com/5BJaBjSi)

Comment: Wait, is `add-credentials` a module you wrote yourself?

Comment: `add-credentials` is folder name, I thing the problem lies on `AddEducation` module which I wrote by myself.